# A Puzzle for a Country

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, word

Caesar's face, in his tongue.
The lines on the circle line.
The opposite of everything that surrounds us.

The answer is the seven-letter name of a country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is...

> **Austria**

Caesar's face, in his tongue

> **Au**, short for gold (Aurum in Latin) and also [Aureus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aureus), a gold coin which Caesar has minted.

The lines on the circle line

> **St**, short for the stations or stops on the Circle Line?

The opposite of everything that surrounds us

> **ria**, which as WAF has wisely noted is air spelled backwards.

Comment: Yours is a lot less contrived than mine. I see this SE as no less collaborative than the others!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about this, but maybe

> Liberia

because

> "liber" is Latin (the language of the Caesars) for "book", which contains a lot of type**face**.

and

> "ER" is the initials of "Edgware Road", which is the station the Circle Line on the underground will take you to if you ride in [either direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_line_(London_Underground)).

and

> "ria" is "air" which surrounds us, backwards.

Comment: Sorry but that's incorrect. Your solution would be libereria.

Comment: @DanielCooper I was thinking the first two elements could overlap. . . Good puzzle.

Comment: I think you're right about the last part and used that (if that's OK).